# What part malfunction could cause a washer abruptly, orderly terminate cycle and freeze?

Tags: washing-machine

I have an old Bosch Nexxt washer that would lock the door properly, start the wash cycle, get the water in the drum (I can see both hoses have flow), then suddenly the "wash" light would turn off, it would drain all the water in an orderly manner (again, I can see it drain freely into the sink, in fact I've replaced the pump because it was making weird noises, to no avail), then unlock the door as if the cycle has ended, and just sit there with the timer stuck at 32-55 mins (depending on the program), lock light on, and no buttons working. No error codes. It can sit like that overnight.
In fact even the drain cycle gets stuck like that even though the pump is new and the water does get drained, it would just unlock the door and sit there with 0:02 remaining.

The belt seems to be fine and the drum rotates fine, too and doesn't wobble unreasonably, although I'm not an expert on that.

Anything else obvious to replace?

Comment: Sounds like the timer  has a few worn teeth on the gears.

Comment: Possibly the water depth sensor Some of these are simple pressure switches sometimes optical but a bad reading may confuse the controller.